# Cannot login to any TTYs - Wrong password

Tags: 12.10, login, tty

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity desktop. I go to TTY1 by pressing keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, where I am asked to enter username and password, which I do, but I get the message "Login incorrect". In my log file `/var/log/auth.log` this entry has been made:

```
Oct 23 13:17:45 SomeName login[3361]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on 'dev/tty1' FOR 'aUser', Authentication failure
```

I do not have the wrong username or password. It is the same username/password I use to log in when Unity starts.

So how come I can't log in to TTY1?

Comment: Have you tried typing out the password once at the TTY (as the username, just to see what is displayed) and once when logged in (use the dash or somthing) just to see if this isn't a keyboard layout issue?

Comment: Yeah it was a keyboard issue =) Numlock wasn't on!

Comment: I was having a problem logging into tty*. I thought my login name was capitalized but i was wrong. For some reason its not. Switched to all lowercase and logged in fine.

Comment: In my case this was caused by my login shell (`/bin/zsh`) not being listed in `/etc/shells`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps your keymap configuration is wrong fo the tty (which is a different setting than Xorg / Unity) and your password is wrong because of this. Try entering your password when you're prompted for your username and see if the characters turn out right; *don't* press enter, but delete your input (since login tries get logged and your password would be in that logfile). If something is wrong, you must set the keymap. In unity, open the terminal application and enter

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

and choose the right layout there. You might have to reboot.

Comment: lol, funny thing. Numlock wasn't on and my password has some numbers in it =) Man do i feel dumb or what. Thing is I googled this issue of course and got all kinds of answers out there so I couldn't imagine that the solution was this simple =)

Comment: I should also say why I want to log into another TTY. I am testing the echo command and now I know it works like a charm. For a newly weed like I am, login to a TTY of your choice, say TTY1, go back to the Unity terminal window and enter: `echo test message > /dev/tty1`.

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause of this error is simply typing your password (or username) wrong. The keymap in the console is often subtly different from the one in X.

**Make sure you're typing the correct password** by first typing it in the login field where you can see if it's being written as expected.

Check that you're typing your username exactly as it should be (including case), by comparing it to the output of `whoami` run in a terminal.

---

Another thing that will cause this exact same error message is if your **login shell is not listed in `/etc/shells`**. Find which shell you're using by searching for your username in `/etc/passwd`:

```
grep "dave" /etc/passwd
```

(replacing `dave` with your username) you should see something like this:

```
dave:x:1000:1000::/home/dave:/bin/zsh
```

The last field (`/bin/zsh`) is your shell. Let's search for it in `/etc/shells`:

```
grep "/bin/zsh" /etc/shells
```

We should see something like this:

```
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

But if you don't, that's what the problem is. Try re-installing `zsh` (or whatever shell is missing from `/etc/shells`), and if that doesn't work, add it manually:

```
echo `/bin/zsh` | sudo tee /etc/shells
```

(we use `tee` because `>` redirection doesn't work with `sudo`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the layout is different.Also to login in console you have to enter `username` wich can be different from your name in profile installation option.For example there is user profile name wich is Andrew but the user pc name can  differ.See it here [image]
I have my profile name on russian and when i login to console i use english login name. If the problem not in this try it http://www.noobslab.com/2012/02/reset-your-forgotten-password-quickly.html