# Ctrl+Alt+F1 - incorrect login

Tags: command-line, tty

I have pressed the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, because I wanted to see the output of my commands as they were being executed, but I got the following error: `incorrect login`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Cannot login to any TTYs - Wrong password](http://askubuntu.com/q/205121/4490)

Comment: In my case this was caused by my login shell (`/bin/zsh`) not being listed in `/etc/shells`.

Answer (score 4):

The most common cause of this error is simply typing your password wrong. The keymap in the console is often subtly different from the one in X.

**Make sure you're typing the correct password** by first typing it in the login field where you can see if it's being written as expected.

---

Another thing that will cause this exact same error message is if your **login shell is not listed in `/etc/shells`**. Find which shell you're using by searching for your username in `/etc/passwd`:

```
grep "dave" /etc/passwd
```

(replacing `dave` with your username) you should see something like this:

```
dave:x:1000:1000::/home/dave:/bin/zsh
```

The last field (`/bin/zsh`) is your shell. Let's search for it in `/etc/shells`:

```
grep "/bin/zsh" /etc/shells
```

We should see something like this:

```
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

But if you don't, that's what the problem is. Try re-installing `zsh` (or whatever shell is missing from `/etc/shells`), and if that doesn't work, add it manually:

```
echo `/bin/zsh` | sudo tee /etc/shells
```

(we use `tee` because `>` redirection doesn't work with `sudo`)

Comment: In addition, no feedback. GUI entry field feeds back you with stars or bullets. TTY login will not echo it and you have to enter correctly (although, Backspace works correctly)

Comment: tee: /etc/shells: Read-only file system This error is occuring

Answer (score 2):

I solved that issue typing the numbers of my password not withe the right-side number keypad, but with the number keys that are over the letters.

Comment: Correct. To login with ctrl+alt+f1, use numbers keys above alphabets keys. not numpad keys

Answer (score 1):

Check Number Lock And Caps Lock

And You can try this too

Open the Terminal Application And Enter Following Code

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

And choose the right layout there.

Comment: and this will ask for password again sir!!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is the first virtual console provided by the `getty`/`agetty` programs, sometimes called `tty1`.

To login there you must to use your Ubuntu user name and the password associated with this user name. If you provide these simple informations correct, you will never see again that error.