# "incorrect login" come at virtual console at the time of trying to fix "nothing appeared issue after login" at ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login, lightdm, tty, pam

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in dual boot along with Windows 10. Everything worked fine. But, today after applying software update and reboot, when I type password at login screen and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing has appeared. Just login screen gone and there was empty screen with default background image only. No `right click` was worked too. I have found some solution at here:
[Type password into login screen, hit enter - nothing happens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390452/type-password-into-login-screen-hit-enter-nothing-happens)

I have opened Virtual Console by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to follow the instruction. After writing the command and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, password filed came, I typed password, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it said `Incorrect Login`!

I have searched for solution and found some at here too. For example: [Ctrl+Alt+F1 - incorrect login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413404/ctrlaltf1-incorrect-login)  Nothing worked for me. Because, someone said using **number** from upper side of keyboard instead of right side of keyboard. But, my password contains **alphabet**. Again, there was some command like

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup 
grep "dave" /etc/passwd
```

etc. But, to execute those command, password is needed and when I type password, there was: `incorrect login`. What can I do now!