# brightness used to work until

Tags: 16.04, brightness

My brightness used to work normally until I did bunch of things I don't know which caused the problem. The brightness from keyboard shows me the indicator on screen but doesn't change, from settings doesn't change either.

What I did before I had the problem was :

First, I updated my system.

Second, I ran:

```
rm -rfv dontDeleteMe && mkdir dontDeleteMe
```

then:

```
rm -rf dontDeleteMe && mkdir dontDeleteMe
```

hoping to reverse it.

Then tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/632341/665251) to repair a `tty` problem.

Output of `sudo lspci -v -s 00:02.0`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: 32
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4050 [size=8]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Output of `sudo lshw -class display`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4050(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Now, What did I do to cause my problem and how can I reverse it?

Comment: None of that really has to do with your brightness except perhaps the update. What graphics card do have?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen 1st Generation Intel HD Graphics

Comment: Can you identify the chip please. Update your question with the output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: ok i've done that

Comment: We need the chip see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tell-which-graphics-vga-card-installed/

Comment: i edited it now , i hope i done it right this time

Comment: It is not your fault, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cant-change-brightness-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: oh noes! you deleted the dontDeleteMe folder! I hope you didn't also push the  dontPushMe button ...