# Difference between Login in Ubuntu 14.04 tty1 and Initial Login

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, login, users

I have installed **Compiz Settings Manager** and misconfigured something, its consequence  was all things disappeared from window other than background. I [found a solution for this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).

Now problem is using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> asks me login,
I tired with login what I used as user (leo) to install earlier and this user I logged in initially from login screen, it says incorrect in `tty1`.
This is the only user I am having as super user.

There is no other user am having in my Ubuntu 14.04.

What is the login other than this?

Comment: Most likely you are either mistyping your password, or the keyboard layout settings are different between the GUI login screen and the tty (causing characters like `@` to appear to be in different places on the keyboard)

Comment: I don't thing so,because user name is leo and password is 1234, I checked its printing properly in that screen while try to view them.

Comment: In that case, have you tried the alternative solution (from the comments in your link) just using a terminal from the GUI i.e. `Ctrl-Alt-t` in place of `Ctrl-Alt-F1`?

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-t not working its not showing anything not working at all.thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact same problem.

1. Installed **Compiz Settings Manager** and **Unity Tweak Tool**
   because Unity was not responding properly.
2. Consequence: Nothing shows, no dash, no bar, nothing... just a wallpaper and the mouse.
3. I tried following this same post: [Difference between Login in Ubuntu 14.04 tty1 and Initial Login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572175/difference-between-login-in-ubuntu-14-04-tty1-and-initial-login)
4. I can't log in to tty1. It says my login is incorrect, but I am typing it right with the good password.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION

If you have numbers in your password we might be in the exact same situation. I read on this page [Cannot login to any TTYs - Wrong password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205121/cannot-login-to-any-ttys-wrong-password) that **NumLock** might not be on and might be causing this problem.

Information about how to install **NumLock**.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock

In my case, I can't find a way to install **NumLock** following the steps on that page.  Via the *System Settings*, when I click on *Keyboard Preferences* everything disappears and I am stuck with just the wallpaper. And I can't open the terminal (CTR + ALT + T does not work). Plus, I can't login to any tty.

(I have to admit that I am more than a newbie and know almost nothing about computers and linux, I just searched forums and read them a lot to come up with all that. So everything here might not be good.)

Let me know if this helps and if any of you have tips on how to fix my situation in the mean time.

Comment: Not the exact same problem, but similar. If it can inspire some of you to find other solutions...

http://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login

Comment: @sunleo Did it solve your problem? What exactly solve it? If it is NumLock, how did you enable/install it if you can't open a terminal? I can't find a way to enable/install it.