# Why is my password not working

Tags: password

I just fixed another bug on my computer and now I don't know what's happening I can't log into my account the password Is correct and I changed it to be sure but when I try to log in a bunch of words pop up for a split second then disappear I haven't been able to read it all but it does say warning. Help me please! My computers bug was that I had stopped in the middle of an update and I would get a message saying that I had a file system error and a maintenance shell would be started so I fixed it by

```
mount -o remount,rw /
dpkg --configure -a
mount -o remount,ro /
sync
reboot
```

Comment: It would help if you added to your quedtion what you did to fix the bug before breaking login

Comment: You've pretty much told us that you did something, and something happened. This question will be closed if you don't provide some details.

Comment: This is what I did

Answer (score 0):

Here's couple of suggestions you could try through either command line or grub -> Advanced Options for Ubuntu -> recovery shell (just remember to remount your system with `sudo mount -o rw,remount /` once you get there):

- Change permissions and ownership on .Xauthority file in your home folder. Refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/223501/295286) for more info. In fact, check permissions on all the files and your home folder itself
- [Reconfigure your keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/a/205129/295286) . Remember how you executed `dpkg --configure -a` ? perhaps you affected something that has to do with the keyboard layout and even though you type correct password, you may be typing it on wrong layout
- Make new user with `adduser newusername`, set password for it with `passwd newusername`, and see if it lets that user log in. If it does, it's most likely something related to your account. You could `chown` your old home folder and files to recover them and eventually abandon your old account.