# Affecting a current install with a Live-CD after current install breaks

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, live-cd

Long story short, battery failed me while in a 15.10 to 16.04 upgrade. Now, I'm stuck with Lubuntu telling me the Light Daemon is lying.

I have my 15.10 CD with me, and was wondering if there's a way to use this to repair or continue the upgrade.

It has access to my files at least.

=========

Update:

I tried [Live CD Recovery - Update Failure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure) but I can't seem to log in to TTY1. The console says it's still a 15.10, but doing the steps on the Terminal says it's Xenial(16.04) now. [Other people's problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205121/cannot-login-to-any-ttys-wrong-password) don't seem to match mine, since it either requests a reboot (for a live cd?) and the `/etc/passwd` has my username on it. And yes, I've tried both my username and real name.

Further more, doing `apt update` or `apt-get update` gets me failed fetches saying

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

... which which led me to do `apt-get -f install` after.

It seemed like there was progress, but I'm still getting failed fetches, saying `Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'`

Comment: `Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'` means that you do not have any Internet.

Comment: Sadly, I did. I was using the same unit to send this topic. Anyway, after all the steps I did, and athough there were a lot of failed fetches, some how, I'm back to normal. I'm scared, but I'm putting in on the answers that the steps above, and the link to Live-CD-Recovery is good enough.

Comment: Did you try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Yes, I did, and, as I mentioned, that command told me to do `apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no real explanation how and why, but the steps described above was enough to fix it. The instructions in [Live CD Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure) were enough, somehow. But use the Terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) if you can't log in.

1. Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.
2. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1 (Or Ctrl-Alt-T if you can't log in)
3. sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
4. sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
5. sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
6. sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
7. sudo chroot /mnt
8. apt update (and follow suggestions when errors occur)
9. apt upgrade (and follow suggestions when errors occur)

It won't look like much happened, and you still have to continue your update, but it was enough to get back to the regular install.